# Sine and Cosine in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Can we surely say that, like in real analysis

```
                                |sin z | < 1
```

and

```
                                |cos z | < 1
```

when z is a complex number, or does it require a proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you defined $\sin$ and $\cos$ on the complex plane? It should be reasonably clear that they are not bounded from definition (as well as from Liouville's theorem, if you know that)

Comment: In fact, these inequalities do not even hold for $\mathbb{R}$ (should be $\leq$, not $<$). To see that it is not true in $\mathbb{C}$, consider $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sin ix$ ($x$ is real).

Comment: In that case how can we find the modulus of sin(z) and cos(z)?

Comment: @hasi You can use hyperbolic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin$ and $\cos$ are non-constant holomorphic functions. By Liouville's theorem, they must be unbounded. In fact,
$$ \cos z = \frac{1}{2}(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}), \sin z = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz} - e^{-iz})
$$
so they grow exponentially on the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 2):

Put $z = iy$ for $y \in \Bbb R$.

$$\cos z = \cos iy = \cosh y \to + \infty \text{ as $y \to \infty$}$$

Also,

$$|\sin z| = | \sinh y| \to + \infty \text{ as $y \to \infty$}$$

Complex $\cos$ and $\sin$ are not even bounded.